# SQL - Confusing Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a 'photos' table:

```
photoID (INT), setID (INT)....
18900 , 234 , ...
18901 , 234 , ...
18902 , 234 , ...
18903 , 249 , ...
18904 , 249 , ...
18905 , 249 , ...
```

I also have a 'photoKeyword' table:

```
photoID (INT), keywordID (INT)
18900 , 12
18900 , 21
18901 , 17
18905 , 26
18905 , 10
```

As you can see from my examples above, photos 18902, 18903 and 18904 do ***NOT*** have any keywords in the photoKeyword table. This is exactly what I am trying to establish.

I am trying to produce a list of photoID's that don't have keywords but one setID at a time. So as you can see, photo 18902 doesn't have keywords and so does 18903 and 18904 but these three photos have two different setID's.

So running this query once, should only return photo 18902. I would then add keywords to this photo so it won't be a problem again. The next time I run the query it should return photo 18903 and 18904, the next set (setID:249) of photos that do not have keywords.

How is this possible? Is it possible just using SQL? I hope you can understand what I looking to achieve, I lost myself just writing about it!!

Any thoughts gratefully received...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
SELECT X.photoID FROM photos X
INNER JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT P.setID FROM 
photos P 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT K.photoID, COUNT(*) C FROM photoKeyword K GROUP BY K.photoID) KC ON KC.photoID = P.photoID
GROUP BY P.setID
HAVING SUM (KC.C) < 1) Y ON X.setID = Y.SetID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT photoID
     , setID
FROM photos 
WHERE photoID NOT IN
      ( SELECT photoID
        FROM photoKeyword
      )
  AND setID =
      ( SELECT setID
        FROM photos 
        WHERE photoID NOT IN
             ( SELECT photoID
               FROM photoKeyword
             )
        ORDER BY setID 
        LIMIT 1
      )
```

Comment: This timed out unfortunately. I have 200,000 rows in photos table and 1,000,000+ in photoKeyword table :)

Comment: Add in your question: a) the tables' definitions (so we know what indexes you have and the datatypes of columns) and b) the EXPLAIN plan of the queries you tried. With 200K+ and 1M+ columns, it would be better if you tried the queries first with smaller tables (to check that they return correct results) and then try the EXPLAIN plan with the big tables to see what indexes are used, that there is no filesort, etc.

Comment: I would guess that an index on `(setID, photoID)` in `photos` table would be good. And an index `photoID` in the `photokeyword` table is essential.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you need which is quite simple... when you think about it...  Ensure your keyword table has an index on the photo id

```
select
      p.PhotoID,
      p.SetID
   from
      Photos p
         LEFT JOIN photoKeyword pkey
            on p.PhotoID = pkey.PhotoID
   where 
      pkey.PhotoID = null
```

By doing a LEFT join, we know it will always attempt to the second table.  Then, if the second table has no matches, we know the ID trying to join on will be null...  So, left join and return only those IDs where the answer is NULL in the second table.